# Migrating a site with a module that doesn't have a version for latest core version

Tags: drush, migrations

I'm working on migrating a site from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8. All content and other things are migrated successfully excepts a module (the *Field collection* module) that is available for Drupal 7, but not for Drupal 8.

Please give guidelines if have any experience with it.

Answer (score 0):

You simply cannot. If the module has a Drupal 8 version you can use it just after enabling the module. But if it doesn't contain a Drupal 8 version you cannot enable or use with your Drupal 8 site installation. Only thing you can do is find an alternative module for the unsupported module that you have used. Or you can change the unsupported modules codes with supported Drupal 8 syntaxes. But I never encourage to do so. Because

1. It effect authors copyrights.
2. You wouldn't be able to update anymore or if you update your module forcefully all the changes you have done will revert back to the original state.

So think twice before doing a change like that. Hope this helps for your question.

Comment: Not exactly correct. If modules provide upgrade paths via migration plugins, this could be possible. That said, people don't use Field Collections in D8 anymore in favor of Paragraphs, which probably doesn't migrate over at all.